# Telerik Spreadsheet localization

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, telerik, .net-5

How to localize the button messages in Telerik Spreadsheet ?

I have the following validation code in a range of cells:

```
myCells.Add(cells.Add().Value(null).Format(NumberFormat)
    .Validation(v => v
    .DataType("number")
    .AllowNulls(true)
    .ComparerType("between")
    .From(minDepth.ToString("0.000"))
    .To(maxDepth.ToString("0.000"))
    .Type("reject")
    .TitleTemplate("Profondeur invalide")
    .MessageTemplate($"Veuillez indiquer une profondeur située entre {minDepth} et {maxDepth} m !"))
    );
```

So, I have localized title and message, but not the buttons...

I also added to the head of the page (_Layout.cshtml) the localization scripts, but didn't help

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/messages/kendo.messages.fr-FR.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/cultures/kendo.culture.fr-FR.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Spreadsheet is not translated, I should add the translation for French, like this, in an additional js file:

```
$(function () {
    /* Spreadsheet messages */
    if (kendo.spreadsheet) {
        kendo.spreadsheet.messages.dialogs =
            $.extend(true, kendo.spreadsheet.messages.dialogs, {
                apply: 'Appliquer',
                save: 'Enregistrer les modifications',
                cancel: 'Annuler',
                remove: 'Retirer',
                retry: 'Réessayer',
                revert: 'Rétablir',
                okText: 'OK',
                formatCellsDialog: {
                    title: 'Format',
                    categories: {
                        number: 'Nombre',
                        currency: 'Devise',
                        date: 'Date'
                    }
                },
                fontFamilyDialog: { title: 'Police' },
                fontSizeDialog: { title: 'Taille de la police' },
                bordersDialog: { title: 'Bordures' },
                alignmentDialog: {
                    title: 'Alignment',
                    buttons: {
                        justtifyLeft: 'Aligner à gauche',
                        justifyCenter: 'Centrer',
                        justifyRight: 'Aligner à droite',
                        justifyFull: 'Justifier',
                        alignTop: 'Aligner le haut',
                        alignMiddle: 'Aligner le centre',
                        alignBottom: 'Aligner le bas'
                    }
                },
                mergeDialog: {
                    title: 'Fusionner les cellules',
                    buttons: {
                        mergeCells: 'Fusionner tout',
                        mergeHorizontally: 'Fusionner horizontalement',
                        mergeVertically: 'Fusionner verticalement',
                        unmerge: 'Annuler la fusion des cellules'
                    }
                },
                freezeDialog: {
                    title: 'Figer les volets',
                    buttons: {
                        freezePanes: 'Figer les volets',
                        freezeRows: 'Figer les lignes',
                        freezeColumns: 'Figer les colonnes',
                        unfreeze: 'Libérer les volets'
                    }
                },
                confirmationDialog: {
                    text: 'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette feuille ?',
                    title: 'Suppression de la feuille'
                },
                validationDialog: {
                    title: 'Validation des données',
                    hintMessage: 'Please enter a valid {0} value {1}.',
                    hintTitle: 'Validation {0}',
                    criteria: {
                        any: 'Toute value',
                        number: 'Nombre',
                        text: 'Texte',
                        date: 'Date',
                        custom: 'Formule personnalisée',
                        list: 'Liste'
                    },
                    comparers: {
                        greaterThan: 'supérieur(e) à',
                        lessThan: 'inférieur(e) à',
                        between: 'entre',
                        notBetween: 'pas entre',
                        equalTo: 'égal(e) à',
                        notEqualTo: 'differente de',
                        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 'supérieur(e) ou égal(e) à',
                        lessThanOrEqualTo: 'inférieur(e) ou égal(e) à'
                    },
                    comparerMessages: {
                        greaterThan: 'supérieur(e) à {0}',
                        lessThan: 'inférieur(e) à {0}',
                        between: 'entre {0} et {1}',
                        notBetween: 'pas entre {0} et {1}',
                        equalTo: 'égal(e) à {0}',
                        notEqualTo: 'differente de {0}',
                        greaterThanOrEqualTo: 'supérieur(e) ou égal(e) à {0}',
                        lessThanOrEqualTo: 'inférieur(e) ou égal(e) à {0}',
                        custom: 'qui satisfait à la formule : {0}'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        criteria: 'Critère',
                        comparer: 'Comparateur',
                        min: 'Min',
                        max: 'Max',
                        value: 'Valeur',
                        start: 'Début',
                        end: 'Fin',
                        onInvalidData: 'Sur les données invalides',
                        rejectInput: 'Rejeter l\'entrée',
                        showWarning: 'Afficher l\'avertissement',
                        showHint: 'Afficher la note',
                        hintTitle: 'Afficher le titre',
                        hintMessage: 'Afficher le message',
                        ignoreBlank: 'Ignorer l\'espace vide',
                        showListButton: 'Afficher le bouton pour montrer la liste',
                        showCalendarButton: 'Afficher le bouton pour afficher le calendrier'
                    },
                    placeholders: {
                        typeTitle: 'Tapez le titre',
                        typeMessage: 'Tapez le message'
                    }
                },
                exportAsDialog: {
                    title: 'Exporter...',
                    defaultFileName: 'Classeur',
                    xlsx: { description: 'Classeur Excel (.xlsx)' },
                    pdf: {
                        description: 'Portable Document Format (.pdf)',
                        area: {
                            workbook: 'Tout le classeur',
                            sheet: 'Feilule active',
                            selection: 'Sélection'
                        },
                        paper: {
                            a2: 'A2 (420 mm \xD7 594 mm)',
                            a3: 'A3 (297 mm x 420 mm)',
                            a4: 'A4 (210 mm x 297 mm)',
                            a5: 'A5 (148 mm x 210 mm)',
                            b3: 'B3 (353 mm \xD7 500 mm)',
                            b4: 'B4 (250 mm x 353 mm)',
                            b5: 'B5 (176 mm x 250 mm)',
                            folio: 'Folio (8.5" x 13")',
                            legal: 'Legal (8.5" x 14")',
                            letter: 'Lettre (8.5" x 11")',
                            tabloid: 'Tabloïd (11" x 17")',
                            executive: 'Executive (7.25" x 10.5")'
                        },
                        margin: {
                            normal: 'Normale',
                            narrow: 'Etroite',
                            wide: 'Large'
                        }
                    },
                    labels: {
                        scale: 'Mettre à l\'échelle',
                        fit: 'Ajuster à la page',
                        fileName: 'Nom du fichier',
                        saveAsType: 'Enregistrer comme type',
                        exportArea: 'Exporter',
                        paperSize: 'Taille du papier',
                        margins: 'Marges',
                        orientation: 'Orientation',
                        print: 'Imprimer',
                        guidelines: 'Lignes directrices',
                        center: 'Centrer',
                        horizontally: 'Horizontalement',
                        vertically: 'Verticalement'
                    }
                },
                modifyMergedDialog: { errorMessage: 'Impossible de modifier une partie d\'une cellule fusionnée.' },
                rangeDisabledDialog: { errorMessage: 'La plage de destination contient des cellules désactivées.' },
                intersectsArrayDialog: { errorMessage: 'Vous ne pouvez pas modifier une partie d\'un tableau' },
                incompatibleRangesDialog: { errorMessage: 'Plages incompatibles' },
                noFillDirectionDialog: { errorMessage: 'Impossible de déterminer la direction du remplissage' },
                duplicateSheetNameDialog: { errorMessage: 'Nom de la feuille en double' },
                overflowDialog: { errorMessage: 'Impossible de coller, car la zone de copie et la zone de collage n\'ont pas la même taille et/ou forme.' },
                useKeyboardDialog: {
                    title: 'Le copier/coller',
                    errorMessage: 'Ces actions ne peuvent pas être invoquées via le menu. Veuillez utiliser les raccourcis clavier à la place :',
                    labels: {
                        forCopy: 'pour copier',
                        forCut: 'pour couper',
                        forPaste: 'pour coller'
                    }
                },
                unsupportedSelectionDialog: { errorMessage: 'Cette action ne peut pas être effectuée sur une sélection multiple.' },
                linkDialog: {
                    title: 'Lien hypertexte',
                    labels: {
                        text: 'Texte',
                        url: 'Adresse',
                        removeLink: 'Supprimer le lien'
                    }
                },
                insertCommentDialog: {
                    title: 'Insérer un commentaire',
                    labels: {
                        comment: 'Commentaire',
                        removeComment: 'Supprimer le commentaire'
                    }
                },
                insertImageDialog: {
                    title: 'Insérer une image',
                    info: 'Faites glisser une image ici, ou cliquez pour la sélectionner',
                    typeError: 'Veuillez sélectionner une image JPEG, PNG ou GIF.'
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Also [asked Telerik to add the translations](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-localize-retry-cancel-buttons-of-the-spreadsheet-messages), if the file is missing